# How to free linked list which is within another linked list?

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, free

I have a `School struct` that holds a linked list of `Student struct`s and each of those `Student struct`s hold a linked list of `Courses struct`s. I am a bit puzzled about how I would be able to free both linked lists. I am particularly unsure about how I would free the `Courses` linked list since it is within another linked list.

```
struct Courses {
    char *courseName;
    int creditValue;
    Courses *next;
} Courses;

struct Student {
    char *studentName;
    int studentAge;
    Courses *coursesList;  //First course (node)
    Student *next; 
} Student;

struct School {
     char *schoolName;
     int schoolAge;
     Student *studentList;  //First student (node)
} School;
```

If someone could show me an example on how I would be able to free both the linked lists that would be great!

Comment: I think you should spend a bit more time to architect your design. Why would the Student struct hold a pointer to the next student? What does "next student" even mean? Same for Courses. After you fix this part, then you'll probably need to have an extra global list of courses, that you will dispose after you dispose all the students.

Answer (score 3):

You should think in terms of ownership: when you free an item, you must free everything it *owns*, that is everything his has a pointer to that is not *owned* by something else.

Along these lines, each list item *owns* the next item, every `School` *owns* its list of `Student`s, every `Student` owns its list of `Courses`.

Your type definitions seem incorrect as you use the same identifier for types and variables. You should rewrite them this way:

```
typedef struct Course Course;
typedef struct Student Student;
typedef struct School School;

struct Course {
    char *courseName;
    int creditValue;
    Course *next;
};

struct Student {
    char *studentName;
    int studentAge;
    Course *courseList;  //First course (node)
    Student *next; 
};

struct School {
    char *schoolName;
    int schoolAge;
    Student *studentList;  //First course (node)
};
```

The function to free everything:

```
void freeSchool(School *school) {
    Student *student = school->studentList;
    while (student) {
        Course *course = student->courseList;
        while (course) {
            free(course->courseName); // if it was allocated
            Course *nextCourse = course->next;
            free(course);
            course = nextCourse;
        }
        free(student->studentName); // if it was allocated
        Student *nextStudent = student->next;
        free(student);
        student = nextStudent;
    }
    free(school->schoolName); // if it was allocated
    free(school);
}
```

Note the similarity between the different levels.  You can also split this function into separate `freeSchool`, `freeStudent` and `freeCourse` functions that you can use to handle individual object deletion in the program.

An elegant way to handle element deletion is for the `freeXXX` function to return the next element and free the node:

```
Courses *freeCourse(Course *course) {
    Course *next = course->next;
    free(course->courseName); // if it was allocated
    free(course);
    return next;
}

Student *freeStudent(Student* student) {
    Student *next = student->next;
    while (student->courseList) {
        student->courseList = freeCourse(student->courseList);
    }
    free(student->studentName); // if it was allocated
    free(student);
    return next;
}

School *freeSchool(School *school) {
    while (school->studentList) {
        school->studentList = freeStudent(school->studentList);
    }
    free(school->schoolName); // if it was allocated
    free(school);
    return NULL;
}
```